# bordermode attribute in place() method of tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

What is the difference between `bordermode = OUTSIDE` and `bordermode = INSIDE` attribute in `place()` method of tkinter in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `tkinter/__init__.py` file:

```
bordermode="inside" or "outside" - whether to take border width of
                                   master widget into account
```

For example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
f1 = Frame(root, borderwidth=5, relief=SUNKEN, width=50, height=50)
f1.pack()
l1 = Label(f1, text="Hi")
l1.place(x=10, y=10, bordermode="outside")

f2 = Frame(root, borderwidth=5, relief=SUNKEN, width=50, height=50)
f2.pack()
l2 = Label(f2, text="Hi")
l2.place(x=10, y=10, bordermode="inside")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: bordermode testing]

So, `outside` counts x and y from the top left corner of the frame ***including*** the border, while `inside` counts it ***without*** the border.